# python list of string converts to list of dict

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert list of string like this

```
['{"What is the purpose of a noun?":"To name something or someone."}', '{"What is the purpose of a verb?":"To show action"}']
```

to list of dict like this

```
[{"What is the purpose of a noun?":"To name something or someone."}, {"What       is the purpose of a verb?":"To show action"}]
```

This is what the original string like in txt file

```
{"What is the purpose of a noun?":"To name something or someone."}
{"What is the purpose of a verb?":"To show action in a sentence."}
```

json module doesn't work

```
a = []
with open("proans.txt",'r') as proans:
    #transform string in the txt file into list of string by \n
    pa = proans.read().split('\n')
    #iterate through the list of string, convert string to dict and put them                           
    #into a list
    for i in range(len(pa)):
        json_acceptable_string = pa[i].replace("\"", "'")
        ret_dict = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
        a.append(ret_dict)
```

I got error like this

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

How do I do to transform this type of list of string to list of dict? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the replace line: `json_acceptable_string = ...`. There's no need to escape quotations.

```
>>> lst = ['{"What is the purpose of a noun?":"To name something or someone."}', '{"What is the purpose of a verb?":"To show action"}']
>>> import json
>>> [json.loads(el) for el in lst]
[{u'What is the purpose of a noun?': u'To name something or someone.'}, {u'What is the purpose of a verb?': u'To show action'}]
>>> [json.loads(el.replace("\"", "'")) for el in lst]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Example similar to the original code with a `StringIO` object:

```
>>> proans = StringIO.StringIO("""{"What is the purpose of a noun?":"To name something or someone."}
... {"What is the purpose of a verb?":"To show action in a sentence."}""")
>>> pa = proans.read().split('\n')
>>> proans
['{"What is the purpose of a noun?":"To name something or someone."}', '{"What is the purpose of a verb?":"To show action in a sentence."}']
>>> for i in range(len(pa)):
...     print json.loads(pa[i])
...
{u'What is the purpose of a noun?': u'To name something or someone.'}
{u'What is the purpose of a verb?': u'To show action in a sentence.'}
```

Comment: It's weird..... When I use console and python source.py command, I get error ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.

Comment: From whatever you're reading (string, file), there could be some lines with nothing but whitespace. If you attempt to decode empty lines, you'll receive an error. Ensure that the file source you're reading from has exactly two lines as you've detailed above. Or, ignore lines with whitespace when you're reading the file.

Comment: @user3908838 maybe you can try my way, haha~